# Docking station for MacBook Pro and HP Probook 430 G6

Tags: macbook-pro, dock

I am trying to find a compatible dock to work on BOTH my 2018 MacBook Pro and my laptop HP Probook 430 G6.
I am running 2 additional HP monitors, mic aux, keyboard & mouse,jabra usb.
I would like to unplug the dock from HP (via USB-C) and swap over the my Mac when required.

Comment: Pick your three top Mac compatible docks. Write tech support for those docks and see if they work with Windows. Lather, rinse repeat.

Comment: Really sorry but your response made no sense. Lather, rinse repeat? This isn’t English.

Comment: Actually it is perfectly fine English. Referring to the instructions of how to use shampoo, oft repeated ad nauseum in TV ads. Basically if the first try with your preferred devices don't work on both platforms pick some more and try again.

Comment: Ok thanks Steve. This seems a rather expensive approach to ‘trial and error’, but if no one knows of one actual device that does work with both these platforms / brands then I will have to take the ‘trial and error’ approach. Many thanks

Comment: It is not expensive except in time. Research a few that work on one platform and contact the manufacturers tech support and see if they work on the other.